# Why Am I getting Bad Access exception on this simple code?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I can't understand why this code is throwing exception of Bad Access:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

TheUserEntity* userEntity = [TheUserEntity alloc];

TheUserModel* userModel = [TheUserModel alloc];

userEntity = [userModel Read:1];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

TheUserEntity and TheUserModel are my own classes, 1 has only properties other only CRUD methods

any help? I'm new in iOS development, thanks

Comment: Hard to say without the code for your classes, but it's a bit fishy that you aren't initializing the objects, just allocating them. It's more common to see something like `SomeObject *myObject = [[SomeObject alloc] init];` in iOS code. That would ensure that when you use it, e.g. `[userModel Read:1]`, the object is properly initialized.

Comment: It's very hard to say the reason, and i think you should init the objects after allocation.i think allocation is just distribute memory without initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `init` on your objects:

```
TheUserEntity* userEntity = [[TheUserEntity alloc] init];
TheUserModel* userModel = [[TheUserModel alloc] init];
```

Your method names should start with lower case letters, that's a convention.